# Change the parsing language

Tags: logic, bison, flex-lexer, boolean-logic, modal-logic

I'm using a modal-SAT solver. This solver is unfortunately using Flex and Bison, both languages that I don't master...

I wanted to change one syntax to another, but I've got some issue to do it, even after tutorials about Flex-Lexer and Bison.

So here is the problem :

I want to be able to parse such modal logic formulas :

[image: a Logical problem in Modal logics as example]

In the previous notation, such formulas were written like this :

`(NOT (IMP (AND (ALL R0 (IMP C0 C1)) (ALL R0 C0)) (ALL R0 C1)))`

And here are the Flex/Bisons file used to parse them :

## alc.y

```
%{

#include "fnode.h"

#define YYMAXDEPTH 1000000

fnode_t *formula_as_tree;

%} 

%union {
   int     l;
   int     i;
   fnode_t *f;  
}

/* Tokens and types */

%token LP RP
%token ALL SOME
%token AND IMP OR IFF NOT
%token TOP BOT
%token RULE CONC
%token <l> NUM 

%type <f> formula 
%type <f> boolean_expression rule_expression atomic_expression
%type <f> other
%type <i> uboolop bboolop nboolop ruleop
%type <l> rule 

%% /* Grammar rules */

input: formula {formula_as_tree = $1;}       
;

formula: boolean_expression {$$ = $1;}
| rule_expression {$$ = $1;}
| atomic_expression {$$ = $1;}
;

boolean_expression: LP uboolop formula RP 
{$$ = Make_formula_nary($2,empty_code,$3);}

| LP bboolop formula formula RP 
{$$ = Make_formula_nary($2,empty_code, Make_operand_nary($3,$4));}

| LP nboolop formula other RP 
{$$ = Make_formula_nary($2,empty_code,Make_operand_nary($3,$4));}
;

rule_expression: LP ruleop rule formula RP {$$ = Make_formula_nary($2,$3,$4);}
;

atomic_expression: CONC NUM {$$ = Make_formula_nary(atom_code,$2,Make_empty());}
| TOP {$$ = Make_formula_nary(top_code,empty_code,Make_empty());}
| BOT {$$ = Make_formula_nary(bot_code,empty_code,Make_empty());}
;

other: formula other {$$ = Make_operand_nary($1,$2);}
| {$$ = Make_empty();}
;

uboolop: NOT {$$ = not_code;}  
;

bboolop: IFF {$$ = iff_code;} 
|        IMP {$$ = imp_code;}
;

nboolop: AND {$$ = and_code;} 
|        OR  {$$ = or_code;} 
;

ruleop: SOME {$$ = dia_code;}
| ALL {$$ = box_code;}       

rule: RULE NUM {$$ = $2;}
;

%% /* End of grammar rules */

int yyerror(char *s)  
{
  printf("%s\n", s);
  exit(0);
}
```

## alc.lex

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

#include "fnode.h"
#include "y.tab.h"

int number;
%}

%%

[ \n\t] ;    
"("      return LP;
")"      return RP; 
"ALL"    return ALL;         
"SOME"   return SOME;
"AND"    return AND; 
"IMP"    return IMP;
"OR"     return OR;
"IFF"    return IFF;
"NOT"    return NOT;
"TOP"    return TOP;
"BOTTOM" return BOT;
"R"      return RULE;
"C"      return CONC;

0|[1-9][0-9]* {   
  sscanf(yytext,"%d",&number);
  yylval.l=number;
  return NUM;
}

.  { 
  /* Error function */
  fprintf(stderr,"Illegal character\n");
  return -1;
}
%%
```

Now, let's write our example but in the new syntax that I want to use :

```
begin
(([r0](~pO | p1) & [r0]p0) | [r0]p1) 
end
```

Major problems for me that are blocking me to parse this new syntax correctly is :

- `IMP (A B)` is now written `~B | A` (as in the boolean logic `(A => B) <=> (~B v A)`).
- `ALL RO` is now written `[r0]`.
- `SOME RO` is now written `<r0>`.
- `IFF (A B)` is now written `(~B | A) & (~A | B)`. (IFF stands `for if and only if`)

Here is the small list of what are the new symbol, even if I don't know how to parse them :

```
"("      return LP;
")"      return RP; 
"[]"    return ALL;         
"<>"   return SOME;
"&"    return AND; 
"IMP"    return IMP;
"|"     return OR;
"IFF"    return IFF;
"~"    return NOT;
"true"    return TOP;
"false" return BOT;
"r"      return RULE;
"p"      return CONC;
```

I assume that only theses 2 files will change, Because it should still be able to read the previous syntaxe, by compiling the source code with other .y and .lex

But I'm asking your help to know exactly how to write it down :/

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who would have the exact same problem (I assume that this problem is quite rare :) )

With the good vocabulary, it's much easier to google the problem and find a solution.

The first notation

`(NOT (IMP (AND (ALL R0 (IMP C0 C1)) (ALL R0 C0)) (ALL R0 C1)))`

is the **ALC format**.

The other notation

`begin
(([r0](~pO | p1) & [r0]p0) | [r0]p1) 
end`

is the [**InToHyLo**](http://hylo.loria.fr/intohylo/hlrmanual.pdf) format.

And there is a tool called the formula translation tool ("ftt") developed and bundled with Spartacus (http://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/spartacus/). It can translate between all the formats of provers.

Using this tool is a little hack who avoid dealing with the Flex/Bison languages.

One just needs to translate one problem to another, problems will be equivalent and it's very fast to translate.

Answer (score 1):

Tommi Junttila's [BC Package](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/bcsat/) implements a language for `Boolean` expressions and circuits using `Bison` and `Flex`.

To study the source files won't fully replace going through a proper `Bison`/`Flex` tutorial, but it certainly should give you a good start.

Comment: Well I already did some bison/flex tutorials, and the parsing for Boolean expressions is already working.

it's even already working for one particular modal-logic syntax, my goal is : how to parse the 2nd syntax, which is really different of what I can find in tutorials unfortunately ... :/

Comment: I can only try to motivate you to look through the BC Package. It implements "unusual" Boolean operators and it should not be too difficult to translate this to your requirements.